# Force ANTLR to read only first commented section from input file and skip the rest comments

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

My input file is having multiple JavaDoc style comments (/** ..... */), I need to read only the very first commented section and skip the rest all commented sections.

### Input.txt

```
/** 
  @Description("Hi there")
  @Input("String")

 */

/**
 * This is the a
 * commented section that we
 * don't want to read.
 */

/**
 * This is the another
 * commented section that we
 * don't want to read.
 */
```

My Lexer Grammar is as below:-

```
lexer grammar AnnotationLexer;

ANNOTATION_START
 : '/**' -> mode(INSIDE), skip
 ;

IGNORE
 : . -> skip
 ;

mode INSIDE;


KEY : '@' [a-zA-Z]+ ;


STRING: '"' (~'"' | ',')* '"' ;


ANNOTATION_END
 : '*/' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE), skip
 ;

IGNORE_INSIDE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
```

Comment: Would it not help, if you were creating another `mode` when you already seen the first javadoc comment?

Comment: Gabor, I tried, but it didn't help, might be I'm missing something, I added another mode to skip everything but no luck.   ANOTHER_START 
  : '/**' mode(ANOTHERMODE)-> skip;
  
 ANOTHER_END 
  : '*/' -> skip;

mode ANOTHERMODE;

ANOTHER_IGNORE 
 : .* -> skip;
it would be very kind, if you can help me to point what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try (I have not tried it though). I am afraid it will not be satisfactory unless you really only read just javadocs and nothing else:

```
lexer grammar AnnotationLexer;

ANNOTATION_START
 : '/**' -> mode(INSIDE), skip
 ;

IGNORE
 : . -> skip
 ;

mode INSIDE;


KEY : '@' [a-zA-Z]+ ;


STRING: '"' (~'"' | ',')* '"' ;


ANNOTATION_END
 : '*/' -> mode(READ_JAVADOC), skip
 ;

IGNORE_INSIDE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip

mode READ_JAVADOC;

JAVADOC_START_AFTER_FIRST
 : '/**' skip
 ;

IGNORE_INSIDE_AFTER_FIRST
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

JAVADOC_END_AFTER_FIRST
 : '*/' skip
 ;
```

Practically this way you have to create all lexer rules two times. Probably it is better to use [semantic predicates](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Semantic+Predicates#SemanticPredicates-PredicatesinLexerRules) in this case (with mutable member fields for the state describing how many javadoc were read) instead of `mode`s.